# How to turn a word into capitals with more than 14 letters?

Tags: python, converters, letter

I want a program that will convert a word into capitals and it doesn't matter how many letters it is.

Now I can go up to 14.

```
print(upper("hello"))
print(upper("dissatisfaction"))
```

says "HELLO" but "DISSATISFACTIOn"

This is the program I have.

I don't just want to add some more (i.e. 15 or 16), I want it so that it doesn't matter how high you go.

So if you had a word like "azertyuiopqsdfghjklwxcvbnm" it will still work.

```
def upper(s):
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'a':
        s = 'A' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'a':
        s = s[:1] + 'A' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'a':
        s = s[:2] + 'A' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'a':
        s = s[:3] + 'A' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'a':
        s = s[:4] + 'A' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'a':
        s = s[:5] + 'A' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'a':
        s = s[:6] + 'A' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'a':
        s = s[:7] + 'A' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'a':
        s = s[:8] + 'A' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'a':
        s = s[:9] + 'A' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'a':
        s = s[:10] + 'A' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'a':
        s = s[:11] + 'A' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'a':
        s = s[:12] + 'A' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'a':
        s = s[:13] + 'A' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'b':
        s = 'B' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'b':
        s = s[:1] + 'B' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'b':
        s = s[:2] + 'B' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'b':
        s = s[:3] + 'B' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'b':
        s = s[:4] + 'B' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'b':
        s = s[:5] + 'B' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'b':
        s = s[:6] + 'B' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'b':
        s = s[:7] + 'B' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'b':
        s = s[:8] + 'B' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'b':
        s = s[:9] + 'B' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'b':
        s = s[:10] + 'B' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'b':
        s = s[:11] + 'B' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'b':
        s = s[:12] + 'B' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'b':
        s = s[:13] + 'B' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'c':
        s = 'C' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'c':
        s = s[:1] + 'C' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'c':
        s = s[:2] + 'C' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'c':
        s = s[:3] + 'C' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'c':
        s = s[:4] + 'C' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'c':
        s = s[:5] + 'C' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'c':
        s = s[:6] + 'C' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'c':
        s = s[:7] + 'C' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'c':
        s = s[:8] + 'C' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'c':
        s = s[:9] + 'C' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'c':
        s = s[:10] + 'C' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'c':
        s = s[:11] + 'C' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'c':
        s = s[:12] + 'C' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'c':
        s = s[:13] + 'C' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'd':
        s = 'D' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'd':
        s = s[:1] + 'D' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'd':
        s = s[:2] + 'D' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'd':
        s = s[:3] + 'D' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'd':
        s = s[:4] + 'D' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'd':
        s = s[:5] + 'D' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'd':
        s = s[:6] + 'D' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'd':
        s = s[:7] + 'D' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'd':
        s = s[:8] + 'D' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'd':
        s = s[:9] + 'D' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'd':
        s = s[:10] + 'D' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'd':
        s = s[:11] + 'D' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'd':
        s = s[:12] + 'D' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'd':
        s = s[:13] + 'D' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'e':
        s = 'E' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'e':
        s = s[:1] + 'E' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'e':
        s = s[:2] + 'E' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'e':
        s = s[:3] + 'E' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'e':
        s = s[:4] + 'E' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'e':
        s = s[:5] + 'E' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'e':
        s = s[:6] + 'E' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'e':
        s = s[:7] + 'E' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'e':
        s = s[:8] + 'E' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'e':
        s = s[:9] + 'E' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'e':
        s = s[:10] + 'E' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'e':
        s = s[:11] + 'E' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'e':
        s = s[:12] + 'E' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'e':
        s = s[:13] + 'E' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'f':
        s = 'F' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'f':
        s = s[:1] + 'F' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'f':
        s = s[:2] + 'F' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'f':
        s = s[:3] + 'F' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'f':
        s = s[:4] + 'F' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'f':
        s = s[:5] + 'F' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'f':
        s = s[:6] + 'F' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'f':
        s = s[:7] + 'F' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'f':
        s = s[:8] + 'F' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'f':
        s = s[:9] + 'F' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'f':
        s = s[:10] + 'F' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'f':
        s = s[:11] + 'F' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'f':
        s = s[:12] + 'F' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'f':
        s = s[:13] + 'F' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'g':
        s = 'G' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'g':
        s = s[:1] + 'G' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'g':
        s = s[:2] + 'G' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'g':
        s = s[:3] + 'G' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'g':
        s = s[:4] + 'G' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'g':
        s = s[:5] + 'G' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'g':
        s = s[:6] + 'G' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'g':
        s = s[:7] + 'G' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'g':
        s = s[:8] + 'G' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'g':
        s = s[:9] + 'G' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'g':
        s = s[:10] + 'G' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'g':
        s = s[:11] + 'G' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'g':
        s = s[:12] + 'G' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'g':
        s = s[:13] + 'G' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'h':
        s = 'H' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'h':
        s = s[:1] + 'H' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'h':
        s = s[:2] + 'H' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'h':
        s = s[:3] + 'H' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'h':
        s = s[:4] + 'H' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'h':
        s = s[:5] + 'H' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'h':
        s = s[:6] + 'H' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'h':
        s = s[:7] + 'H' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'h':
        s = s[:8] + 'H' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'h':
        s = s[:9] + 'H' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'h':
        s = s[:10] + 'H' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'h':
        s = s[:11] + 'H' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'h':
        s = s[:12] + 'H' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'h':
        s = s[:13] + 'H' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'i':
        s = 'I' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'i':
        s = s[:1] + 'I' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'i':
        s = s[:2] + 'I' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'i':
        s = s[:3] + 'I' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'i':
        s = s[:4] + 'I' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'i':
        s = s[:5] + 'I' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'i':
        s = s[:6] + 'I' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'i':
        s = s[:7] + 'I' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'i':
        s = s[:8] + 'I' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'i':
        s = s[:9] + 'I' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'i':
        s = s[:10] + 'I' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'i':
        s = s[:11] + 'I' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'i':
        s = s[:12] + 'I' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'i':
        s = s[:13] + 'I' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'j':
        s = 'J' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'j':
        s = s[:1] + 'J' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'j':
        s = s[:2] + 'J' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'j':
        s = s[:3] + 'J' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'j':
        s = s[:4] + 'J' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'j':
        s = s[:5] + 'J' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'j':
        s = s[:6] + 'J' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'j':
        s = s[:7] + 'J' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'j':
        s = s[:8] + 'J' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'j':
        s = s[:9] + 'J' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'j':
        s = s[:10] + 'J' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'j':
        s = s[:11] + 'J' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'j':
        s = s[:12] + 'J' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'j':
        s = s[:13] + 'J' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'k':
        s = 'K' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'k':
        s = s[:1] + 'K' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'k':
        s = s[:2] + 'K' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'k':
        s = s[:3] + 'K' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'k':
        s = s[:4] + 'K' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'k':
        s = s[:5] + 'K' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'k':
        s = s[:6] + 'K' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'k':
        s = s[:7] + 'K' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'k':
        s = s[:8] + 'K' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'k':
        s = s[:9] + 'K' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'k':
        s = s[:10] + 'K' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'k':
        s = s[:11] + 'K' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'k':
        s = s[:12] + 'K' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'k':
        s = s[:13] + 'K' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'l':
        s = 'L' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'l':
        s = s[:1] + 'L' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'l':
        s = s[:2] + 'L' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'l':
        s = s[:3] + 'L' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'l':
        s = s[:4] + 'L' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'l':
        s = s[:5] + 'L' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'l':
        s = s[:6] + 'L' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'l':
        s = s[:7] + 'L' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'l':
        s = s[:8] + 'L' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'l':
        s = s[:9] + 'L' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'l':
        s = s[:10] + 'L' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'l':
        s = s[:11] + 'L' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'l':
        s = s[:12] + 'L' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'l':
        s = s[:13] + 'L' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'm':
        s = 'M' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'm':
        s = s[:1] + 'M' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'm':
        s = s[:2] + 'M' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'm':
        s = s[:3] + 'M' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'm':
        s = s[:4] + 'M' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'm':
        s = s[:5] + 'M' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'm':
        s = s[:6] + 'M' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'm':
        s = s[:7] + 'M' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'm':
        s = s[:8] + 'M' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'm':
        s = s[:9] + 'M' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'm':
        s = s[:10] + 'M' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'm':
        s = s[:11] + 'M' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'm':
        s = s[:12] + 'M' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'm':
        s = s[:13] + 'M' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'n':
        s = 'N' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'n':
        s = s[:1] + 'N' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'n':
        s = s[:2] + 'N' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'n':
        s = s[:3] + 'N' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'n':
        s = s[:4] + 'N' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'n':
        s = s[:5] + 'N' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'n':
        s = s[:6] + 'N' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'n':
        s = s[:7] + 'N' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'n':
        s = s[:8] + 'N' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'n':
        s = s[:9] + 'N' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'n':
        s = s[:10] + 'N' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'n':
        s = s[:11] + 'N' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'n':
        s = s[:12] + 'N' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'n':
        s = s[:13] + 'N' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'o':
        s = 'O' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'o':
        s = s[:1] + 'O' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'o':
        s = s[:2] + 'O' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'o':
        s = s[:3] + 'O' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'o':
        s = s[:4] + 'O' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'o':
        s = s[:5] + 'O' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'o':
        s = s[:6] + 'O' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'o':
        s = s[:7] + 'O' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'o':
        s = s[:8] + 'O' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'o':
        s = s[:9] + 'O' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'o':
        s = s[:10] + 'O' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'o':
        s = s[:11] + 'O' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'o':
        s = s[:12] + 'O' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'o':
        s = s[:13] + 'O' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'p':
        s = 'P' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'p':
        s = s[:1] + 'P' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'p':
        s = s[:2] + 'P' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'p':
        s = s[:3] + 'P' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'p':
        s = s[:4] + 'P' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'p':
        s = s[:5] + 'P' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'p':
        s = s[:6] + 'P' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'p':
        s = s[:7] + 'P' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'p':
        s = s[:8] + 'P' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'p':
        s = s[:9] + 'P' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'p':
        s = s[:10] + 'P' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'p':
        s = s[:11] + 'P' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'p':
        s = s[:12] + 'P' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'p':
        s = s[:13] + 'P' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'q':
        s = 'Q' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'q':
        s = s[:1] + 'Q' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'q':
        s = s[:2] + 'Q' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'q':
        s = s[:3] + 'Q' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'q':
        s = s[:4] + 'Q' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'q':
        s = s[:5] + 'Q' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'q':
        s = s[:6] + 'Q' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'q':
        s = s[:7] + 'Q' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'q':
        s = s[:8] + 'Q' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'q':
        s = s[:9] + 'Q' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'q':
        s = s[:10] + 'Q' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'q':
        s = s[:11] + 'Q' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'q':
        s = s[:12] + 'Q' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'q':
        s = s[:13] + 'Q' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'r':
        s = 'R' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'r':
        s = s[:1] + 'R' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'r':
        s = s[:2] + 'R' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'r':
        s = s[:3] + 'R' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'r':
        s = s[:4] + 'R' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'r':
        s = s[:5] + 'R' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'r':
        s = s[:6] + 'R' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'r':
        s = s[:7] + 'R' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'r':
        s = s[:8] + 'R' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'r':
        s = s[:9] + 'R' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'r':
        s = s[:10] + 'R' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'r':
        s = s[:11] + 'R' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'r':
        s = s[:12] + 'R' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'r':
        s = s[:13] + 'R' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 's':
        s = 'S' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 's':
        s = s[:1] + 'S' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 's':
        s = s[:2] + 'S' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 's':
        s = s[:3] + 'S' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 's':
        s = s[:4] + 'S' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 's':
        s = s[:5] + 'S' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 's':
        s = s[:6] + 'S' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 's':
        s = s[:7] + 'S' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 's':
        s = s[:8] + 'S' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 's':
        s = s[:9] + 'S' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 's':
        s = s[:10] + 'S' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 's':
        s = s[:11] + 'S' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 's':
        s = s[:12] + 'S' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 's':
        s = s[:13] + 'S' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 't':
        s = 'T' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 't':
        s = s[:1] + 'T' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 't':
        s = s[:2] + 'T' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 't':
        s = s[:3] + 'T' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 't':
        s = s[:4] + 'T' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 't':
        s = s[:5] + 'T' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 't':
        s = s[:6] + 'T' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 't':
        s = s[:7] + 'T' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 't':
        s = s[:8] + 'T' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 't':
        s = s[:9] + 'T' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 't':
        s = s[:10] + 'T' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 't':
        s = s[:11] + 'T' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 't':
        s = s[:12] + 'T' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 't':
        s = s[:13] + 'T' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'u':
        s = 'U' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'u':
        s = s[:1] + 'U' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'u':
        s = s[:2] + 'U' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'u':
        s = s[:3] + 'U' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'u':
        s = s[:4] + 'U' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'u':
        s = s[:5] + 'U' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'u':
        s = s[:6] + 'U' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'u':
        s = s[:7] + 'U' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'u':
        s = s[:8] + 'U' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'u':
        s = s[:9] + 'U' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'u':
        s = s[:10] + 'U' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'u':
        s = s[:11] + 'U' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'u':
        s = s[:12] + 'U' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'u':
        s = s[:13] + 'U' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'v':
        s = 'V' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'v':
        s = s[:1] + 'V' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'v':
        s = s[:2] + 'V' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'v':
        s = s[:3] + 'V' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'v':
        s = s[:4] + 'V' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'v':
        s = s[:5] + 'V' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'v':
        s = s[:6] + 'V' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'v':
        s = s[:7] + 'V' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'v':
        s = s[:8] + 'V' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'v':
        s = s[:9] + 'V' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'v':
        s = s[:10] + 'V' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'v':
        s = s[:11] + 'V' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'v':
        s = s[:12] + 'V' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'v':
        s = s[:13] + 'V' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'w':
        s = 'W' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'w':
        s = s[:1] + 'W' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'w':
        s = s[:2] + 'W' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'w':
        s = s[:3] + 'W' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'w':
        s = s[:4] + 'W' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'w':
        s = s[:5] + 'W' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'w':
        s = s[:6] + 'W' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'w':
        s = s[:7] + 'W' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'w':
        s = s[:8] + 'W' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'w':
        s = s[:9] + 'W' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'w':
        s = s[:10] + 'W' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'w':
        s = s[:11] + 'W' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'w':
        s = s[:12] + 'W' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'w':
        s = s[:13] + 'W' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'x':
        s = 'X' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'x':
        s = s[:1] + 'X' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'x':
        s = s[:2] + 'X' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'x':
        s = s[:3] + 'X' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'x':
        s = s[:4] + 'X' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'x':
        s = s[:5] + 'X' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'x':
        s = s[:6] + 'X' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'x':
        s = s[:7] + 'X' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'x':
        s = s[:8] + 'X' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'x':
        s = s[:9] + 'X' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'x':
        s = s[:10] + 'X' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'x':
        s = s[:11] + 'X' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'x':
        s = s[:12] + 'X' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'x':
        s = s[:13] + 'X' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'y':
        s = 'Y' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'y':
        s = s[:1] + 'Y' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'y':
        s = s[:2] + 'Y' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'y':
        s = s[:3] + 'Y' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'y':
        s = s[:4] + 'Y' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'y':
        s = s[:5] + 'Y' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'y':
        s = s[:6] + 'Y' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'y':
        s = s[:7] + 'Y' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'y':
        s = s[:8] + 'Y' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'y':
        s = s[:9] + 'Y' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'y':
        s = s[:10] + 'Y' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'y':
        s = s[:11] + 'Y' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'y':
        s = s[:12] + 'Y' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'y':
        s = s[:13] + 'Y' + s[14:]
    if len(s) >= 1 and s[0] == 'z':
        s = 'Z' + s[1:]
    if len(s) >= 2 and s[1] == 'z':
        s = s[:1] + 'Z' + s[2:]
    if len(s) >= 3 and s[2] == 'z':
        s = s[:2] + 'Z' + s[3:]
    if len(s) >= 4 and s[3] == 'z':
        s = s[:3] + 'Z' + s[4:]
    if len(s) >= 5 and s[4] == 'z':
        s = s[:4] + 'Z' + s[5:]
    if len(s) >= 6 and s[5] == 'z':
        s = s[:5] + 'Z' + s[6:]
    if len(s) >= 7 and s[6] == 'z':
        s = s[:6] + 'Z' + s[7:]
    if len(s) >= 8 and s[7] == 'z':
        s = s[:7] + 'Z' + s[8:]
    if len(s) >= 9 and s[8] == 'z':
        s = s[:8] + 'Z' + s[9:]
    if len(s) >= 10 and s[9] == 'z':
        s = s[:9] + 'Z' + s[10:]
    if len(s) >= 11 and s[10] == 'z':
        s = s[:10] + 'Z' + s[11:]
    if len(s) >= 12 and s[11] == 'z':
        s = s[:11] + 'Z' + s[12:]
    if len(s) >= 13 and s[12] == 'z':
        s = s[:12] + 'Z' + s[13:]
    if len(s) >= 14 and s[13] == 'z':
        s = s[:13] + 'Z' + s[14:]
    return s
```

Comment: You should learn about *loops*.

Comment: It must have taken quite some persistence to write all that before googling how to convert a string to upper case in Python.

Comment: ... and read about [mre]. Emphasis on the **minimal**

Comment: khelwood I didn't write it all by hand, you can do it with a macro.

Comment: Go to the macro menu in the edit window.

Comment: @Lucky Very well, I take it back. Not persistent. Merely misguided.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`upper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) on the string:

```
# DISSATISFACTION
print("dissatisfaction".upper())
# AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLWXCVBNM
print("azertyuiopqsdfghjklwxcvbnm".upper())
```

Comment: Is there any limit at all?

Comment: That's the best Python offers @Lucky